# Remove 1px border under UINavigationBar - not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

```
@IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!

self.navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

The code above works if the View Controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller and uses `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBack`... etc, but it doesn't work when using an IBOutlet (my example is not embedded in nav controller). The navigation bar is not translucent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Put this in you view controller (not in the uinavigationbar).

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I also tried placing it in AppDelegate but that also didn't, I think your answer only works for new instances and not already created ones.

Comment: @jskidd3 This should work, and I just tested it should work for bars that are not in a `UINavigationController` as well. Try setting `translucent=false` too

Comment: Did you put this code in your view controller's viewDidLoad method?

Comment: I can verify that this works as well, for BarStyle=UIBarStyleBlack at least.

Answer (score 3):

Where exactly are you calling the appearance settings for a NavBar? When I try the following:

```
[self.myNC.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.myNC.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have the desired effect.Could you provide us with a little more context perhaps?

Comment: I am calling it in the view controller's viewDidLoad in which the navigationBar is present in. Could you write your answer in Swift instead, please? I can't seem to find a setShadowImage method, only a shadowImage property.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a nav bar without nav view controller, you can try to set `navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES`. I have a separate `UIToolbar` and this approach works now.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with an IBOutlet for the navigation bar.

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

}
```

Double check that your navigation bar is set as a referencing outlet to the view controller.

[image: IBOutlet]

Here is a sample project showing that it works as expected:
http://bjtitus.s3.amazonaws.com/NavBarBorderTest.zip